# Is there a way to make a input lowercase in python?

Tags: python

I am having a problem where I get a error saying that the .lower() function doesnt exist, can someone help me?

but i am pretty sure that i have used the right syntax because it worked before.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what mistake you've made if you don't show us the code that has the problem, preferably just the smallest relevant part.

Comment: You'll have to post your code for us to help you.

Comment: @AKrossvector is it a List or a String?

Comment: it was a string, the problem is fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To covert a string to lower - use the functions .lower() and input()

input(string) prints out the string `s` (this can be a prompt, for example)

`"enter input here:"`
and, to assign it to a variable `my_input`:

```
my_input = input("Enter something:")
```

#### Similarly, to make the input lowercase:

Directly:

```
input("enter input").lower()
```

With the variable:

```
my_lower_input = my_input.lower()
my_lower_input # now contains the input, but lowercase.
```

#### Trough a Bash Terminal:

```
python3 -c 'my_input=input("enter something: "); print(my_input)'
enter something: abc
abc
```

#### Similarly, with lower case (using Lambda as an example this time)

```
python3 -c 'inputToLow = lambda m:(m.lower());print(inputToLow(input("enter any string here:\n")))'
enter any string here: HeLLo WORLD
hello world
```

#### References

[input - At Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: What would be the use of creating a list containing each letter of the string individually lowercased? The question didn't state or imply a need for something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @Kemp - Didn't consider that

Comment: Thank you, i realised the mistake, i wasn't indenting the line properly, it kept on coming out as a runtime error and i was looking at my monitor like i was a big doofus(which i was) . Thank you!

Comment: @AKrossvector No problem. We are here to help!  and,  On this site - (although we try to minimize it as much as possible) (I say this because you are new) On this site, like on any other site on the internet, replies - and posts; can seem - offending/ or "not kind"; - Just wanted to say **Do not get discouraged!** Especially when someone points out problems/or gives constructive feedback! (Not any specific reason I say this here, in a comment - Just thought of mentioning).  Good luck on your python Programming!  //Nice weekend.

Answer (score 1):

The `.lower()` method is indeed the method to make string text lowercase in Python. It's use is as follows:

```py
string = 'FOOBAR'
print(string.lower())
```

This code will give the output:

```
> foobar
```

Comment: This is a solution too - worth reading in my opinion :)